# Characterization of autocovariance function

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, autocorrelation, stochastic-processes

I a studying  from Brockwell and Davis Time series Theory and Methods. I have the theorem 1.5.1. I am not clear with the first part of the proof. The theorem is the next one:
[image]

In the first part of the proof, I can't see how to compute:
$$0\leq Var(a'Z_t)$$

I have that $Var(a'Z_t)=a'Var(Z_t)a$, then $Var(Z_t)=Var(X_t-EX_t)$ since $EX_t$ is a constat I would get $Var(Z_t)=Var(X_t)$ , but I can't see how this is equal to $E[Z_tZ_t']$.

Comment: By definition of variance, $Var(Z_t)=E(Z_tZ_t')-E(Z_t)E(Z_t)'$. The second term is zero by construction.

Comment: @MossMurderer (+1) but I wouldn't call this the definition

Comment: @Taylor: You're right, it took me a while to realise though...

Comment: What is it? if is not the definition?

Comment: @Boris: It follows from the definition after doing some math. The definition is $Var(Z_t)=E[(Z_t-E[Z_t])^2]$.